# two different accounts, login failure

Tags: bug, chat

My real username is "laminin". I have 132 reputation. Someone proposed me to talk in the chat room:
[Freeware that converts structure in a conformational model?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/freeware-that-converts-structure-in-a-conformational-model/17191?noredirect=1#comment26780_17191)

When I click that my user name is changed towards user68212 (the account which has been created at first when connecting with a google account) which has almost no reputation point. I can't write in the chat room because there is a notification, that I must have 20 reputation to talk there. Can you unpin and delete my user68212 account from my actual account laminin?

Comment: Has it started working by this point?  Your user account for chat is linked to your main account at this point, so I don't know if someone fixed it or not.  If you weren't logged into Chem at the time, the system may have logged you in under an older "cookie based" account that you had in the past.

Comment: If it's still not working, I will follow up with the appropriate people.

Comment: It has started before because once I used Google Login instead of StackExchange Login. Now I deleted the browsers' cookies and was now able to enter the chat as laminin. Nevertheless I'd be very glad if appropiate people can unpin (or even delete the user68212) which is attached on my laminin account.

Comment: I think if you delete the cookie, the account is effectively gone, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Yes, fortunately the account is gone. Thank you!